# Find closest longitude and latitude in array from user location - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The following piece of code was instrumental to an iOS app I finished recently:

```
var closestLocation: CLLocation?
var smallestDistance: CLLocationDistance?

for location in locations {
  let distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(location)
  if smallestDistance == nil || distance < smallestDistance {
    closestLocation = location
    smallestDistance = distance
  }
}
```

My question is pretty simple: **how would this piece of code look in Java for Android Studio?**

This is my first run at Java and Android Studio, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using the Location class. It is used to store locations in Latitude and Longitude. It also has predefined function for calculating distance between points - `distanceBetween()`.

```
Location closestLocation;
int smallestDistance = -1;
```

Assuming locations is an `ArrayList<Location>()`

```
for(Location location : locations){
    int distance = Location.distanceBetween(closestLocation.getLatitude(),
                           closestLocation.getLongitude(),
                           location.getLatitude(),
                           location.getLongitude());
    if(smallestDistance == -1 || distance < smallestDistance){
        closestLocation = location;
        smallestDistance = distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a large set of latitudes and longitudes to construct the ArrayList<Location>. How would that be written?

Comment: If you are just creating latitude longitude pair then consider making `ArrayList<LatLng> list`. Create new LatLng objects like `LatLng location = new LatLng(latitudeValue, longitudeValue);` and add this to your list like `list.add(location)`.

Comment: I have the following: 

'LatLng location1 = new LatLng(35.789882, -78.690761); LatLng location2 = new LatLng(35.789882, -78.690761); ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>.add(location1).add(location2);'

It's throwing an error saying it cannot resole the symbol "add."

I'm sure this should be obvious, but I appreciate all your help. It's going a long way.

Comment: `ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();` then in separate statement `list.add(location1);` and `list.add(location2);`

Comment: Thank you very much! The good people on StackOverflow save the day again.

Answer (score 2):

```
Location closestLocation = null;
float smallestDistance = -1;

for(Location location:mLocationsList){
float distance  = currentLocation.distanceTo(location);
 if(smallestDistance == -1 || distance < smallestDistance) {
    closestLocation = location
    smallestDistance = distance
  }
}
```

With `mLocationsList` being an iterable collection of Location-objects and `currentLocation` being already set

Answer (score 1):

It would look something like this (locations need to be iterable and userLocation must be set):

```
    Location closest;
    float smallestDistance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Location l : locations) {
        float dist = l.distanceTo(userLocation);
        if (dist < smallestDistance) {
            closest = l;
            smallestDistance = dist;
        }
    }
```